# Importing a library project from Git into my project didn't work (Eclipse)

Tags: java, git, android-library

I have been trying to import https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu library into my project, but it didn't work.

I have clone the repo and imported into my project.

I have set in library settings android that it is library and imported.

Nothing happens. Other libraries are working.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from the link you provided this is a gradle project (built with gradle), so I'm assuming you need to build it and then add it to your project as a dependency.

You need to have gradle installed on your machine and then you can build a jar by calling

```
gradle fatJar
```

in the root folder of library.

Comment: How to install gradle into eclipse? Can you give me some more information?

Comment: There is a plugin for Eclipse https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-integration-eclipse-0, but you still need to have gradle installed on your machine.

I would suggest to follow this tutorial: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html and use the gradle through the command line, since you are not using it actively in your project.

Comment: Okay i will try to follow this tutorials, but he said that we can use his library as library project alternative.

Comment: I have tried building gradle into the root folder of library but build failed.

Comment: Well, after a second look at the github page I can see that it says that you should add the library as a module to you project, and not as a library.

Other way would be to add the jar which can be downloaded from maven central http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|a%3A%22CircularFloatingActionMenu%22

Comment: And i should download javadoc.jar or sources.jar?

Comment: I have add in java build path javadoc.jar file and added in libs folder. Still i can't use library.